# Is it possible to create a List using anonymous types on both sides (input and output) of the declaration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, anonymous-types

Is it possible to create a list using anonymous types on both sides (input and output) of the declaration?

I would like to do something like this:

```
List<Class1> list = getList<Class1>(List<Class2> list2);
```

...using a method declared something like this:

```
public static List<T1> getList<T1>(List<T2> list2)
{
    List<T1> list = new List<T1>();
    foreach (var item in list2) {
        list.Add(new T1(item));                
    }
    return list;
}
```

Basically, I just want to **convert** a list containing class2 items to a new list containing class1 items. My idea was to set up a constructor in Class1, doing the convert job (from class1 to class2). But there might be better ways of doing such a thing.
These are my classes:

```
public class Class2
{
    string prop1 { get; set; }
    string prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    string member1 { get; set; }
    string member2 { get; set; }

    //constructor: 'converts' class1 in class2
    public Class1(Class2 class2)
    {
        this.member1 = Util.getThisAndThat(class2.prop1);
        this.member2 = Util.doBunchOfStuff(class2.prop2);
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking. It looks like (aside from the declaration of the generic method, which is missing a type parameter), you're on the right track. Are you asking if there is a better way? or are you getting errors?

Comment: If this is specific to your `Class1` and `Class2`, then why not just have a method `public static List<Class1> getList(List<Class2> list2) { \\... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer mentioned `AutoMapper`, but I would use it directly.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Class1, Class2>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.member1,
                 opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Util.getThisAndThat(src.prop1)))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.member2,
                 opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Util.doBunchOfStuff(src.prop2)));

public static List<T1> getList<T1>(List<T2> list2)
{
    return Mapper.Map<List<T2>, List<T1>>(list2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at your solution when I've got AutoMapper up and running :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below, if it works. For each different type like `Class1` and `Class2` you need to implement the interface. But what you are actually looking for seems like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

```
public interface ILoadable<T> 
{
    void LoadFrom(T other);
}

public class Class1 : ILoadable<Class2>
{
    public void LoadFrom(Class2 other) 
    {
        // Do property mapping here
    }
}

public static List<T1> GetList<T1, T2>(List<T2> list2) where T1 : ILoadable<T2>, new()
{
    List<T1> list = new List<T1>();
    foreach (var item in list2) {
        T1 t1 = new T1();
        t1.LoadFrom(item);
        list.Add(t1);                
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm :) But like @user2266486 said, it's probably better to avoid constructors with other classes as parameters. I'll try to use AutoMapper later on. Thanks!

Comment: I had your solution up and running (actually marked it as my accepted answer) but now that I've got AutoMapper doing most of the work, @Romoku answer is working slightly better for me. Thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 1):

You can just write:

```
List<Class1> list1 = list2.Select(class2 => new Class1(class2)).ToList();
```

But for it to work, Class1 must have a constructor that takes Class2 as a parameter, which is not great in my opinion.

I would write a separate static method which converts a Class2 instance to a Class1 instance:

```
public static Class1 ToClass1(Class2 class2)
{
  //return a Class1 instance
}
```

And do:

```
List<Class1> list1 = list2.Select(class2 => ToClass1(class2)).ToList();
```

If you're happy to have some coupling between both classes, you can add a [conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) to one of them and do:

```
List<Class1> list1 = list2.Cast<Class1>().ToList();
```